# vue - data reference another data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I very new in vue, how can `mylist` `random`, can get the same value from `somerandom`

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
        somerandom:"foo",
        mylist:{
            random: this.somerandom
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

model init an object with value.
can set value by default or run func after computed or mounted

```js
data() {
    return {
      somerandom: '',
      someOther: [],
    }
},
computed: {
    useRandom() {
        this.somerandom = this.rand();
    }
},
methods: {
    rand(){
       return 'random';
    }
}
```